# Calculating a day given a Date

Tags: java, date

From a given Date I need to calculate midnight of its day. Here's what I came up with. It's so ugly that I figure there must be a better way.

```
private Date day(Date creation) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(creation);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return calendar.getTime();
}
```

Suggestions?

Kent

Comment: Good Lord - first Alan Kay, now Kent Beck.  SO is the place to be...

Comment: It's worse than that, the code you posted doesn't account for time zone, which you may or may not care about.

Comment: simple check this out [here](http://developer-dot-android.blogspot.com/2012/03/date-into-day-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should consider the built-in date API obselete. Instead use the Joda date and time API.

Here's a drop-in replacement for your method.

```
private Date day(Date creation) {
    return new DateMidnight(creation).toDate();
}
```

Here's a simple test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Date creation = new Date();
    final Date midnight = new Foobar().day(creation);
    System.out.println("creation = " + creation);
    System.out.println("midnight = " + midnight);
}
```

The output is:

```
creation = Sun May 31 10:09:38 CEST 2009    
midnight = Sun May 31 00:00:00 CEST 2009
```

Answer (score 5):

[JODA](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) might have a better solution, at the cost of another dependency on a library.  I'm looking at its [DateMidnight property](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/index.html).  I'm sorry that I can't answer more authoritatively, but I'm not a JODA user myself.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for local time, that's the best you're going to get. And although you may consider it ugly, there's (potentially) a lot going on behind the scenes.

If you want midnight UTC, the following will work:

```
public static void main(String[] argv)
throws Exception
{
    final long MILLIS_PER_DAY = 24 * 3600 * 1000L;

    long midnightUTC = (System.currentTimeMillis() / MILLIS_PER_DAY) * MILLIS_PER_DAY;
}
```

**Edit**: I really don't recommend using local dates in "production" code. They cause more trouble than they're worth -- consider a person on the US west coast who suddenly finds his/her "day" trimmed by 3 hours because an east coast computer has a different idea of midnight.

Answer (score 1):

[JODA](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) is the way to go if you have serious calendar needs, at least until [JSR-310](https://jsr-310.dev.java.net/) gets into the JDK (1.7 maybe, if not 1.8).

That being said, there are a couple of things that could be done to make this code a little nicer.

```
import static java.util.Calendar.*;

...

private static final List<Integer> TIME_FIELDS = 
    Arrays.asList(HOUR_OF_DAY, MINUTE, SECOND, MILLISECOND);

private Date day(Date creation) {
     Calendar c = getInstance();
     c.setTime(creation);
     for(int field : TIME_FIELDS) c.set(field, 0);
     return c.getTime();
}
```

That won't win any performance awards. You could do a standard for loop relying on the specific field values (the Calendar class has a FIELD_COUNT field kind of implying you can do something like that) but that risks issues across JDK implementations and between versions.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [date4j](http://www.date4j.net) library :

```
DateTime start = dt.getStartOfDay();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way you're going to make this code significantly better is by a change in representation.  For example,

- Represent the day by the "absolute date" system explained by Nachum Dershowitz and Ed Reingold in [Calendrical 
  Calculations](http://emr.cs.uiuc.edu/home/reingold/calendar-book/index.shtml).
- Represent the time by counting seconds from midnight.  Or if you need sub-second resolution, count milliseconds.

From your brief example I can't tell at what points in your program you need to be compatible with existing `Date` and `Calendar` classes, or if you can create a useful subclass using a saner representation.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't programmed Java in a while, but you might be able to call this [set method](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int,%20int,%20int)) passing in the current values for year, month, and day. Although from reading a little close, you may have to call clear first.  This may or may not be less verbose than using your current method.

Answer (score 0):

This is just the complement of the originally posted code. It sets the Year, Month, and Day in a new GregorianCalendar object, instead of clearing everything but the Year, Month, and Day in the calendar variable. It's not much of an improvement, but I think it's clearer to say which fields you are copying, instead of which fields you're ignoring.

```
public Date day(Date creation) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(creation);
    return new GregorianCalendar(
            calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).getTime();
}
```

Personally, I think I'd go with the Joda library proposed by others.